# AWS kinesis put record throwing invalid security token

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have a nodejs aws client that puts records to a kinesis stream. I am pretty sure the credentials i use are valid. However I get this error:

```
error:   Error is  UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid
    at Request.extractError (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:43:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:671:14)
```

Using the aws-cli also returns a similar error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the PutRecord operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

aws configure list shows the correct credentials being used.

Is there anything apart from provding the access key,secret access key and the region that i should provide ?

Comment: check if you have any creds in your <user_home>/.aws/credentials that you might have configured and are being used.

Comment: Yes , the ~/.aws/credentials file also has the right credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that AWS wasn't reading the supplied credentials (even though the script could print out the credentials ! ). I was using docker to run this script. Changed the way kinesis object is formed and it worked:

```
new AWS.Kinesis({
    accessKeyId: <AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>,
    secretAccessKey: <AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>,
    region: <AWS_REGION>,
  });
```